# Authenticating a message with HMAC vs AES-CBC

Tags: signature, hmac, mac

Given some string `s` I want to sign, are following methods are equivalent to produce message with signature, assuming it does not matter whether `s` is visible in message or not?

1. `s` + HMAC(`s`, secret_key)
2. AES_CBC(`s` + `string_of_zeroes`, secret_key)

And validation:

1. recalculate HMAC of first part of message and compare it to second one
2. decrypt message and verify that it ends with `string_of_zeroes`

If that is true, `string_of_zeroes` of what length should be taken to make them equivalent?

Comment: HMAC produces a message authentication code, not a signature.

Comment: AFAIK MAC is a signature. At least I do not know another term for generic way to validate message integrity.

Comment: @SergeyAlaev you might want to calculate the HMAC over the AES

Comment: @YorickdeWid AES is faster than HMAC, also it hides message itself. That's why I'm wondering whether is it safe.

Comment: @SergeyAlaev, no MAC is not a signature. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code#Security) for differences. That said, what mode-of-operation are you planning on using for AES?

Comment: HMAC output has fixed size (same as underlying hash function); how are you going to get fixed-sized output using AES?

Comment: CBC mode, fixed output is not needed as output is *signed message*, not signature (or code)

Comment: Maybe you are asking about CBC-MAC security? - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBC-MAC

Comment: @kludg thanks, that's exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: @SergeyAlaev If CBC-MAC is what you are looking for, I suggest you read [_Why I hate CBC-MAC_](https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2013/02/15/why-i-hate-cbc-mac/).

Answer (score 13):

> Given some string `s` I want to [integrity protect], are following methods are equivalent to produce message with signature, assuming it does not matter whether `s` is visible in message or not?

Absolutely not; with AES_CBC, if the attacker modifies one particular block of the ciphertext, then the decryption of the modified ciphertext will have two blocks modified (the one corresponding to the modified block, and one block after that).

Hence, if `s` is (at least) two blocks long, an attacker can freely modify the first block of the ciphertext; the decryption will still have the `string of zeros` still in place (as that wasn't modified), and so the attacker has succeeded in undetectably modifying the string.

If you need a MAC, use a MAC (alternatively, authenticated encryption).  And, make sure that a MAC is appropriate (that is, both the sender and the receiver share a secret key, and you don't mind if the receiver were able to generate valid-looking messages of his own).

Answer (score 4):

If you need authenticated encryption having only AES available then AES-CMAC is an option. It is standarized in [RFC 4493](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4493). You must use different keys for encryption and signing.